# Python is throwing "syntax error" while using @app.route

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Python is throwing "Syntax Error" when I compile the code below.

```
File "app.py", line 11
    @app.route('/')
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm not sure what it means.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import urllib.request
import json
import time

app = Flask(__name__ ,template_folder='template')
namep = "PewDiePie"
namet = "TSeries"
key = "MY_API_KEY"

@app.route("/")

for x in range(5):
 time.sleep(2)
 datat = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername="+namep+"&key="+key).read()
 datap = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername="+namet+"&key="+key).read()
 subt = json.loads(datat)["items"][0]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"]
 subsp = json.loads(datap)["items"][0]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"]
 def main():
    return render_template('index.html', pewds_sub = subsp, tseries_sub = subt)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

Any help regarding this is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define the function after the route decorator, i.e. after @app.route

Updated code

```
@app.route("/")
def function_main():
    #all logics here
    return render_template('index.html', pewds_sub = subsp, tseries_sub = subt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to process your calculations inside function else try to pass those argument in defined function.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import urllib.request
import json
import time

app = Flask(__name__ ,template_folder='template')
namep = "PewDiePie"
namet = "TSeries"
key = "MY_API_KEY"

@app.route("/")
 def main():
    for x in range(5):
        time.sleep(2)
        datat = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername="+namep+"&key="+key).read()
        datap = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername="+namet+"&key="+key).read()
        subt = json.loads(datat)["items"][0]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"]
        subsp = json.loads(datap)["items"][0]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"]
    return render_template('index.html', pewds_sub = subsp, tseries_sub = subt)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case,

I initiated a **try block** just above for the *database connection* and **forget to put catch block**, that's why I have encountered this error.

so I suggest anyone facing the same error,

should check the code above `@app.route('/')` because if you have `import flask`

properly this should work pretty fine syntax error in this statement usually indicates that you might have a problem above this line and not at that line.